# Reducing the text content inside a custom quantum gate in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I have prepared a parameterized custom quantum gate in qiskit by converting a quantum circuit into a gate through `QuantumCircuit.to_gate()`. However, the text content in each of the quantum gates `2QU1`, `2QU2`, and `2QU3` makes the gates too wide in appearance.

Is there a way to change the display of the content of all the parameters (15 parameters in each custom gate) inside the custom parameterized gates? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib circuit drawer displays up to 16 parameters. This number is hardcoded as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

On the other hand, Latex circuit drawer displays up to 4 parameters. So, you can use Latex drawer if it's OK. You will get a result as the below:

[image]

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the suggestions. But, is there a way to change the display of the quantum circuit in qiskit where the `2QU1`, `2QU2`, and `2QU3` gates display as small gates that does not explicitly displays all the parameters of each of those custom gates?